# iOS5 position fixed: moves when changing orientation landscape to portrait

Tags: ios5, css-position

.. here is the dummy: http://cybergrafic.at/projects/apprunner/

position is fixed; the elements inside the fixed div are `float:left`; if you change from portrait to landscape, everything works fine; if you change from landscape to portrait, the fixed div moves 30px to the RIGHT, after touching the pad it moves into the correct position;

tested with iPad 1 & updated iOS 5.

Comment: I can't see your example, but if you're describing what I think you're describing, it appears to be a Mobile Safari bug. Something like this happens to me on iOS when my web app is launched from the Home Screen (a "web clip"). I worked around it by adding a window orientationchange event handler that removes position: fixed and then calls setTimeout() to put position: fixed back again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I believe, is that mobile safari doesn't always repaint the view fast enough.

Toggling `position:fixed` on the element does cause a repaint, but it also resulted in a "flash" for me in my tests.

I just found this, works great:

```
    bruteForceRepaint: function() {
        var ss = document.styleSheets[0];
        try { ss.addRule('.xxxxxx', 'position: relative'); }
        catch(e) {}
    }
```

[force mobile safari to repaint / redraw](http://mrdarcymurphy.tumblr.com/post/5574489334/force-mobile-safari-to-repaint-redraw)